# How to cache a geojson file in d3?

Tags: performance, caching, d3.js, geojson

I'm using a really large geojson file to draw a map in d3. I've reduced the size of the geojson file as much as possible and it's still huge at 30 mgbs. I want to store it in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to make the page more efficient at least for those who are refreshing the page but since d3 references the file directly, and `localStorage` returns a string, I'm not sure how to go about caching it.

```
d3.json("geo.json", function(data){/*draw the map*/});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I think I've got it. First, I minified the files as much as possible and got them down to the 5mgbs range.

```
d3.json("geo.json", function(data){

localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data));
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('data');
data=JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

/*draw the map*/ });
```